# Adding new site column to existing content type on multi language sites

Tags: 2010, feature, upgrade

I'm using the declarative SharePoint feature upgrade approach to :
1. Add a new custom column to site columns gallery
2. Add the new custom column to an existing content type

There are two variation sites (base and target) each one with resource files supporting required localization (including display name in both languages for the new custom column). The upgraded content type is already in use in lists with content in both variation sites.

After triggering the feature upgrade, the new custom column is added to to site collection root web site column gallery and to the target content type as expected. Because I configured the 'PushDown' attribute of AddContentTypeField element to true, the change on content type is propagated to the lists that were already using it and the new column is added as expected.

The issue is that the display name for the added new custom column in both lists (each one on a different variation-language site) is on the same language, meaning the wrong language for one of the sites. The display name for the new column on the field definition is using a resource-based approach to get the display name for each of the used languages.

Can someone please point me to some information regarding how I should be doing it to get it working as it should ? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Since you are propergating different DisplayName, you do have them defined somewhere... eg. mapped in the regional resource files.
The declarative approach would be to set the

```
DisplayName = $Resources:<projectName>,<propertyName>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Theodor. All columns, including the new custom column, use resource files to define their display names ...